# Visual Studio: Is there a keyboard shortcut to jump between code editor window and find results?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I can't seem to find the exact keyboard shortcut I'm looking for.

When I do a "Find in Files" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>), the keyboard navigation automatically jumps to the Find results, and I can navigate the results with the arrow keys; the code editor window updates itself as I do so, and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> pops me from the Find Results Window to the code editor Window.

Now, this is great for the initial search, but what if I want to bounce back and forth, say, if I need to make changes around a few different places in my find results?

Is there a keyboard shortcut to jump back from the code editor window to the find results?

I'm using MSVS 2013, if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the General Development keyboard scheme, try: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>.

This is bound to the `Window.NextPane` which is where you just came from, so it should take you back.

Also, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> is `Window.NextToolWindowNav` which pops up a nav selection which makes it easy to move around. This nav selection is the same one for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> which, once open, can be navigated up, down, left and right via arrow keys.